# Regex match middle not in a list?

Tags: regex, regex-negation

I am trying to match strings that do not contain certain strings in between the first and last characters. These strings come as a list, here it is:

```
this
is
a
demo
```

There can be more. I have written

```
1(?!this|is|a|demo).*2
```

Here is [my regex live demo](https://regex101.com/r/nrPVz8/2). It matches `1demo12` only, I need it to match `1demoo2`, too.

More test cases:

```
1this2       # do not want match
1is2         # do not want match
1a2          # do not want match
1demo2       # do not want match
1demoo2      # want match
1demo12      # want match
```

I try to use `Negative Lookahead` but failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```js
^1(?!(?:this|is|a|demo)2$).*2$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/PV3InF/2).

*Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `1` - a `1` char
- `(?!(?:this|is|a|demo)2$)` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if there is `this`, `is`, `a` or `demo` followed with `2` and end of string immediately to the right of the current location
- `.*` - any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `2` - a `2` char
- `$` - end of string.

Comment: middle is not only one character, I have change the example, can you just have a look

Comment: @distinct The same technique, just use a group for multicharacter alternatives, `^1(?!(?:this|is|a|demo)2$).*2$`